# A theorem related to prime numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there any theorem in number theory which says there is a prime number between $n$ and $(1+\epsilon)n$?

Comment: Bertrand's Postulate (actually a theorem) is the statement that this holds for $\varepsilon = 1$. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Arturo Magidin: I mean like for arbitrary small $\epsilon.$

Comment: Um... what is $\epsilon$?  A positive integer?  This is obvious not true if $\epsilon$ can be anything less than $1$ or can be $0$.  If $\epsilon$ must be an integer it'd be more direct to simply say between $n$ and any $kn; k\ge 1;k\in \mathbb N$ can be more succinctly stated as: for any natural $n$ there is a prime between $n$ and $2n$.  And that is Bertrands Postulate.

Comment: For sufficiently large $n$, yes. $\pi((1+\varepsilon)n) - \pi(n)$ goes to infinity as $n\to\infty$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate#Better_results
So for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $n_0$ (which depends on $\epsilon$) such that if $n>n_0$, then there is a prime between $n$ and $(1+\epsilon)n$.

Comment: " I mean like for arbitrary small ϵ"  Oh... well that's obviously false.  Just let $\epsilon < \frac 1n$.  There is not prime between $n$ and $(1 +\epsilon )n < n+1$.  THere is no *integer* between $n$ and $(1+\epsilon)n$.

Comment: @fleablood: Clearly $0 < \epsilon < 1.$

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Great.Thanks.

Comment: And obviously for any $n< p$ we can find an $\epsilon$ small enough so that $n(1+\epsilon) < p$ so this is obviously false.  However Arturo Magidin comment is that for any fixed epsilon you can find an $n$ large enough where it is true.  But it obviously isn't true for *all* epsilon and *all* $n$.  And the converse for all $n$ you can find an $\epsilon$ but that epsilon could be large and close to $1$.